# How to include timestamps in Spring Boot Actuator Prometheus metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Boot 2.5.4 and Actuator with Micrometer and Prometheus support.
When I open the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint, I see metrics like these:

```
# HELP jvm_threads_live_threads The current number of live threads including both daemon and non-daemon threads
# TYPE jvm_threads_live_threads gauge
jvm_threads_live_threads 28.0
```

Note that there is no timestamp attached to that metric. However, according to [OpenMetrics / Prometheus spec](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/), it is possible to add a timestamp to the metrics output.

**My question:** How can you tell Spring Boot Actuator to generate and add a timestamp to the metrics it creates? I have not found any documentation on it. Thanks!

### References

My `pom.xml` dependencies look like this:

```xml
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My `application.yaml` like this:

```yaml
# Application name. Shows up in metrics etc.
spring:
  application:
    name: "some_app_name"

# Expose application on port 8080
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}

# Expose all Actuator endpoints (don't do this in production!)
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micrometer [doesn't support this at the moment](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2627). The team's recommendation is to use the Prometheus Java Client directly for metrics where the timestamp is important to you.